Why doesn't clock transition time affect my timing analysis (PrimeTime)?
This is a somewhat tool-specific question, so if it's not permitted here please feel free to delete.

I am simulating the circuit attached with cells from the lsi_10k.lib built-in library (though I have now since used other librairies and still have the problem below, so I don't think it has anything to do with my tech library) for my own personal practice and have enforced the constraints below in the Tcl script I pass to PrimeTime:
#-----------------------------------------------#
# ENFORCE CONSTRAINTS
#-----------------------------------------------#
# Define clock plus its natural latency
create_clock -name CLK -period 10 [get_ports Clock]
set_propagated_clock [get_clocks CLK]
set_clock_uncertainty 1 -hold [get_clocks CLK]
set_clock_uncertainty 1 -setup [get_clocks CLK]
set_clock_latency 1 -source [get_clocks CLK]
set_clock_transition 2 [get_clocks CLK]
set_input_delay -clock CLK 2 [all_inputs]
set_output_delay -clock CLK 2 [all_outputs]

As you can see, I do have a set_clock_transition command. Nevertheless, there is zero dependence on the value I provide there (whether 0 or very large). All other constraints are observable in the outputted timing report, except for set_clock_transition. Why is this?
I expect delay through the inverters (at least the first one on the path! In the report below this is the I1/Z (IVA) cell delay of 0.49 time units) to slow down, but this is not observed. The lsi_10k.lib library does seem to have enough information about the relevant cells that a delay calculator should compute different delays in different slew rate situations too, I think?
Setup analysis output:
****************************************
Report : timing
-path_type full_clock_expanded
-delay_type max
-slack_lesser_than 1000000.00
-max_paths 1
-sort_by slack
Design : MyComp
Version: T-2022.03
Date : Tue Aug 13 21:44:09 2024
****************************************


Startpoint: F3 (rising edge-triggered flip-flop clocked by CLK)
Endpoint: OUT (output port clocked by CLK)
Path Group: CLK
Path Type: max

Point Incr Path
---------------------------------------------------------------
clock CLK (rise edge) 0.00 0.00
clock source latency 1.00 1.00
Clock (in) 0.00 1.00 r
I1/Z (IVA) 0.49 1.49 f
I4/Z (IV) 0.67 2.15 r
I5/Z (IVP) 0.21 2.36 f
I6/Z (IVA) 0.31 2.68 r
F3/CP (FD1) 0.00 2.68 r
F3/Q (FD1) 1.37 4.05 f
OUT (out) 0.00 4.05 f
data arrival time 4.05

clock CLK (rise edge) 10.00 10.00
clock network delay (propagated) 1.00 11.00
clock reconvergence pessimism 0.00 11.00
clock uncertainty -1.00 10.00
output external delay -2.00 8.00
data required time 8.00
---------------------------------------------------------------
data required time 8.00
data arrival time -4.05
---------------------------------------------------------------
slack (MET) 3.95


1

Can anyone set me straight on what I'm missing? I've consulted the PrimeTime User Guide and seem to be doing the right thing. No matter how much I sharpen or flatten my input clock slew rate, I see zero differences in my timing outcomes (expected in particular at I1/Z).
